# What is the name of this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question, terminology

If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a number such that $0\leq a <\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, then $0=a$

Does anyone know the name of this statement? (If it has one)

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it is equivalent to the Archimedean property of the real numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)

Comment: "$0$ is the infimum of the set $\Bbb R^+$"?

Comment: It might be worth comparing it to [non-Archimedean ordered fields](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field).

Comment: If I recall correctly, Charles C Pugh in his real analysis book calls this the $\epsilon$-principle (though I've never heard that terminology used anywhere else).

Comment: Don't think the Archimeidean property is used: You just need $a/2>0$ and the trichotomy of the ordering.

Comment: Shrink lemma,  like in series.

Comment: It's a special case of the squeeze theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: It just follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field?

Comment: "If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a number such that $0 \leq a \lt \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $0 = a$" also holds !?

Comment: Indeed a hidden premise is the trichotomy of the ordering like @ArcticChar said.